# Удаление записи из DataSet

Tags: база-данных, delphi

Требуется скопировать запись из таблицы в другую таблицу, и соответственно удалить эту запись из исходной таблицы, но не удалять из базы данных.
Копирование выполняется, а вот с удалением проблемы. В качестве датасетов таблиц используется MemTableEh.

Функция удаления у меня выглядит так:

```
function TSGSDuoTreeFrame.MoveFieldToTarget(var sDataSet, tDataSet: TMemTableEh): Boolean;
{*Процедура копирует текущую запись из основного датасета
  в датасет привязанных устройств. В исходном датасете эту запись требуется удалить*}
var
  i, id: Integer;
  res: Boolean;
begin
    sDataSet.Open;
    tDataSet.Open;
    tDataSet.Append;
  Result := False;

  id := sDataSet.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger;

  sDataSet.First;
  while not sDataSet.Eof  do
  begin
    if (sDataSet.FieldByName('ID').AsInteger = id) then
    begin
    for i := 0 to sDataSet.Fields.Count-1 do
      sDataSet.Fields[i].Value := tDataSet.Fields[i].Value; 

      sDataSet.Delete;
      Break;
    end;
    sDataSet.Next;
  end;

  Result := True;

end;
```

Выдает ошибку Empty SQL Statement.

Подозреваю, что проблема в том, что из базы тоже нужно удалять, подскажите в чём может быть проблема?)

Проблема решена, всем спасибо! Всего-то нужно было в свойствах MemTableEh поставить галочку CashedUpdates.

Comment: Кажется, вы хотели скопировать запись из `sDataSet` в `tDataSet`, но код делает наоборот - копирует из `tDataSet` в `sDataSet`, прямо в удаляемую затем запись. Странно, что Вы не получили ошибку на этом копировании (ведь вызов `sDataSet.Edit` отсутствует). Впрочем, я давно не работал с `TMemTableEh` - может быть, он и так позволяет...

Comment: Вы правы, это мой косячёк, не посмотрела когда код копировала, правильно из sDataSet в tDataSet.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш код и ваше описание задачи расходятся. Согласно вашему коду вы копируете запись из датасета-приемника (`tDataSet`) в исходный датасет (`sDataSet`). Необходимо заменить `sDataSet.Fields[i].Value := tDataSet.Fields[i].Value;` на `tDataSet.Fields[i].Value := sDataSet.Fields[i].Value;`.

К тому же, зачем вы циклом пробегаете по всем записям исходного датасета, если хотите скопировать только текущую запись? Тут цикл, полагаю, излишен.

И еще, просто рекомендации: вы называете функцию

> Функция удаления

Однако, она у вас выполняет на самом деле перенос записи (даже по названию на английском, хотя и не совсем удачное название) и внутри выполняет два действия: копирование и удаление. Вообще метод должен выполнять только одно действие, и просто рекомендация - перепроектируйте вашу функцию **переноса записи** из одного датасета в другой на использование двух функций: функции копирования и функции удаления. Вам же легче потом будет отлаживать, вносить изменения, да и повторно использовать код можно будет.

Comment: Спасибо за рекомендации, изначально так и предполагалось, что будет две функции Переноса и Удаления. Проблему с удалением решу, и вынесу его в отдельную функцию.